# Reading Targa File. Missing Dark Colors?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, parsing, graphics, tga

**Due to being new, I can only have two links and can not post my images. Sorry for the inconvenience of having to copy+paste addresses**

I am parsing a Targa (.tga) image file with code similar to that found at **steinsoft.net/index.php?site=Programming/Code%20Snippets/Cpp/no8**

After retrieving the data into the unsigned char array, I print it out into a log to check manually. It seems that darker colors are not being parsed for whatever reason.

---

**The Simple Print Code**

```
file.open( save );

//using while( tga.data[ i ] != NULL ) resulted in ~400,000 lines of garbage being appended
for( unsigned i = 1; i <= ( tga.width * tga.height * tga.byteCount ); i++ )
{
    if( tga.data[ i ] == NULL )
        break;

    file << ( int )tga.data[ i ] << ",";

    if( ( i % 3 ) == 0 )
        file << "\n";
}

file.close( );
```

---

**Example**

Dark : **https://i.stack.imgur.com/qefIA.png** : http://pastebin.com/8JeJwP2w

Light : **https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNTIK.png** : http://pastebin.com/s2sW0XfM

As you can see, the line at the top of the image is not included when it is a dark color (black in this instance), but it is there when it is light (a pink [255,53,204]).

Does anyone have any information on why this may be happening?

---

**Specs**

Windows Vista

Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Professional

Targa is saved as 24-bit NOT compressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, why do you check if the `data[i]==NULL`? There might be 0-pixels (black), so keep them all in. You basically check if the color is 0 and then you exit your loop. Just read all pixels no matter the value.

Comment: d'oh! It was late at night and that never even crossed my mind. I just didn't want crash from accessing beyond the size of the array (though there are better ways to do that).